# How do I assure a one time delivery with Paypal Express

Tags: node.js, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I do not have a programming problem. I want to make my payments robust with no redundant state in my server. I also want to avoid that a hacker forces a double delivery using the same paymentID.

I verify the express payment on my server using ...

```
paypal.payment.get(paymentID, function (error, payment)
```

it returns a json as expected ...

```
{
    "id": "PAY-69X53496F3347611XLM3WZ2A",
    "intent": "sale",
    "state": "created",
    "cart": "4MV88706BE6849235",
    "payer": { ...
```

It shows that it was paid, I want to mark it as delivered. Can I set that payment at Paypal in a state that indicates that it is delivered?

For instance ...

```
"state": "delivered",
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not get any suggestions so I assume there is none and fell back to a simple database where I persist the delivery state locally.